# What language supports a whitespace-based syntax for html like sxml?

Tags: html, xml, yaml, sxml

I remember I once saw a language which allowed me to write html as follows:

```
html
  head
    title
     "Welcome"
  body
    div class=header
      ul
        li "menu 1"
        li "menu 2"
```

**Does anybody know which language/library this is?**

It looks a lot like python code. Where indentation is leading and no end tags are required.

I know about SXML and YAML, but they are not exactly what i mean.

I prefer a simple language that follows the XML infopath internal tree model. And not a template language with logic or whatsoever.

Comment: Was it [Haml](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haml)?

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/zen-coding/ is not the same but it is close

Answer (score 1):

I think I found it:
http://shpaml.webfactional.com/

However I am not 100% sure.

If somebody else find some other library please let me know!

Answer (score 0):

I can only think of Jade, this is the template engine Node.js uses. However I am not sure it can be used without Node.